# Height of box with arrow

Tags: boxes

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{$\longrightarrow$}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen, the height of the box is too small.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 1992, the Computer Modern arrows were changed to make for a larger head; already in the old version the bounding box didn't cover the whole tip and it was not changed after the modification to the tips, for backwards metric compatibility.

With the `old-arrow` package one can see the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

x \fbox{$\varrightarrow$} (old style)

x \fbox{$\rightarrow$} (new style)

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can fix the bounding box using the fact that the stem is at the math axis and the lower part of the tip sits on the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\srightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\strutarrow\rightarrow}%
}
% define similarly the other arrows you need

% the generic macro
\newcommand{\strutarrow}[2]{%
  \vrule width 0pt height 2\fontdimen22
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 2
  {#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\fbox{$\rightarrow$} \fbox{$\srightarrow$}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

x \fbox{$\rightarrow$} (normal)

x \fbox{$\srightarrow$} (with strut)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Enrico! (Btw. when I zoom in it is easy to see that the long arrow 
(when I switch to `\longrightarrow`) is composed of a short arrow and a line segment. Can this be "smoothed" out?)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg That’s how long arrows are made, some viewers may have issues at certain resolutions. It has nothing to do with the bounding box.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a strut or perhaps better add a zero width rule similarly centred on the math axis, of whatever size you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{.} \fbox{$a$} \fbox{$\longrightarrow$} \fbox{\strut$\longrightarrow$}

\fbox{$\vcenter{\hrule height 15pt width 0pt}{\longrightarrow}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm! When I zoom in it is easy to see that the long arrow is composed of a short arrow and a line segment. Can this be "smoothed" out?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg one way would be to use a font that has long arrows eg stix, or you could tweak the definition of `\joinrel ` to have more overlap

Comment: @SvendTveskæg much as it pains me to say so, I suspect you should move the tick in the general direction of egreg

Comment: Okay; I will. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

hkl \raisebox{2\fontdimen22\textfont2}{ \fbox{\raisebox{-2\fontdimen22\textfont2}{$ \longrightarrow $}}} amn 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Hmmm! When I zoom in it is easy to see that the long arrow is composed of a short arrow and a line segment. Can this be "smoothed" out?

Comment: I didn't notice that – thought it was a glyph on its own. You can use this: `\newcommand\mylongrightarrow{\mathrel{\relbar\mkern-4mu\rightarrow}}`. The difference in length is very small: about 0.7pt.

Comment: When I define `\newcommand*\mylongrightarrow{\mathrel{\relbar\mkern-4mu\righ‌​tarrow}}
\newcommand*\reaktionspil{$\vcenter{\hrule height 60pt width 0pt}{\mylongrightarrow}$}` and compile, I get the error `\mylongrightarrow ...el {\relbar \mkern -4mu\righ 
                                                  ‌​tarrow}
l.126 \fbox{\reaktionspil}`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Strange… I've just tested your code and I have no problem. Could you post a complete example reproducing your problem?

Comment: I'm very tired ... going to bed now. I'll post tomorrow. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Now I finally got the time to try your code again. It compiles fine (I must have been very tired yesterday) but the arrow is still composed of a short arrow and a line segment. *I'll start a new question.*

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Of course it composed of a short arrow and a line segment, since there's no glyph for `\longrightarrow` in the font.  But do you SEE there are two elements on zooming with the kerning I use?