# Long arrow composed of line segment and shorter arrow

Tags: symbols

Consider the following [code from egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410749/15874):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\strutarrow}[2]{%
  \vrule width 0pt height 2\fontdimen22
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 2
  {#2}%
}
\newcommand{\srightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\strutarrow\longrightarrow}%
}

\begin{document}

\fbox{$\srightarrow$}

\end{document}
```

[image: arrow]

As can be seen, the long arrow is composed of line segment and shorter arrow.

How do I "fix" this so that there isn't a dent in the arrow?

Comment: the default overlap is `\DeclareRobustCommand\joinrel{\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}}` you could redefine it to be `-4mu` and have more overlap and a slightly shorter arrow or use a font that has long arrows that don't need building up like: → ⟶

Comment: The code for the strut has nothing to do with this. Try with just `\longrightarrow`, but it's only a question of font hinting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\longrightarrow` is defined as

```
\def\longrightarrow{\relbar\joinrel\rightarrow}
```

You can correct the flaw mentioned above for example by this:

```
\def\longrightarrow{\relbar\joinrel\mkern-1mu\rightarrow}
```

Note that the problem has nothing in common with the code mentioned in your question. The code only adds the invisible strut (depending on the math style).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a small negative space using the `\!` macro. Inserting it before `#2` seems to fix the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\strutarrow}[2]{%
  \vrule width 0pt height 2\fontdimen22
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 2
  \!{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\srightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\strutarrow\longrightarrow}%
}

\begin{document}
\fbox{$\srightarrow$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This cannot help because `\!` is inserted between strut and `\longrightarrow`. But the problem is in `\longrightarrow`.